# Hibernate @DynamicUpdate on an immutable entity

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

Suppose that I have a Hibernate entity whose fields are altered via new instance creation (e.g. [Lombok builder](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder)).

Does that mean that `@DynamicUpdate` is not going work? Is is required to change the fields via setters in this case?

P.S. Here is an example

```java
@Table
@Entity
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
class Person {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
}
...
Person person = personRepository.findById(1).orElseThrow();
personRepository.saveAndFlush(
    person.toBuilder()
          .firstName("newName")
          .build()    // creates new instance
);
```

Comment: Probably in this case you should use `@DynamicUpdate` in conjunction with `@SelectBeforeUpdate` (see the note [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#annotations-hibernate-dynamicupdate))

Comment: IMHO, the notions  "immutable entity" and dynamic update  are incompatible with each other.

Comment: What do you mean by an 'entity whose fields are altered via new instance creation'? `em.merge()`?

Comment: @crizzis I added an example to the question